# Default Values for ASP.NET Core TagHelper Properties

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

If I have the following tag helper:

```
[Flags]
public enum SubresourceIntegrityHashAlgorithm
{
    SHA256 = 1,
    SHA384 = 2,
    SHA512 = 4
}  

[HtmlTargetElement("script", Attributes = "asp-subresource-integrity")]
public class FooTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-subresource-integrity")]
    public SubresourceIntegrityHashAlgorithm HashAlgorithms { get; set; } 
        = SubresourceIntegrityHashAlgorithm.SHA256;

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How can use the default value I have given on the property above so that I do not have to provide the property with a value when using it:

```
<script asp-subresource-integrity src="..."></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script asp-subresource-integrity="SubresourceIntegrityHashAlgorithm.SHA256" src="..."></script>
```

## Update

I've raised an issue on the MVC GitHub page [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4157) as this should really be a built in feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an attribute to the list of attributes of the `HtmlTargetElement`, the attribute is required for the tag helper to be applied and it requires a value.

If you try to use it without value or an empty value you will get an error like:

```
<my-script asp-subresource-integrity src="foo.js"></my-script>
```

> Tag helper bound attributes of type 'WebApplication7.TagHelpers.SubresourceIntegrityHashAlgorithm' cannot be empty or contain only whitespace

**Even if you change the type of the attribute to a nullable type like string, you will get the same error**. So far the best way I have found of for having optional attributes is not to have them in the list of attributes:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("script")]
```

Of course that means your tag helper would be applied regardless of whether there is an attribute `asp-subresource-integrity` or not, and you most likely don't want that. A couple of ways you can solve this:

- You can use another attribute as a "marker" attribute, that has no effect other than limiting your tag helper to be applied when the marker attribute is present.

  ```
  [HtmlTargetElement("script", Attributes = "my-script")]
  public class FooScriptTagHelper : TagHelper
  {
      ...
  }

  <!--This uses the default value-->
  <script my-script src="foo.js"></script>
  <!--This uses a specific value-->
  <script my-script asp-subresource-integrity="..." src="foo.js"></script>
  ```
- The alternative would be using a custom tag name, and then you can omit the attribute when using the default value:

  ```
  [HtmlTargetElement("my-script")]

  <!--This uses the default value-->
  <my-script src="foo.js"></my-script>
  <!--This uses a specific value-->
  <my-script asp-subresource-integrity="..." src="foo.js"></my-script>
  ```

Bear in mind that even with those approaches, when you use the attribute you still need to provide a value. I mean, you can either add or omit the attribute, but if the attribute is there, it needs a non empty value:

```
<!--This will still throw an exception-->
<my-script asp-subresource-integrity src="foo.js"></my-script>
```

Comment: Could you inject a class into the constructor of the tag helper and have those values in that class?

Comment: @PeterKellner, yep dependency injection works with tag helpers